Почему не работают изображения при копировании в GULP?
Всем привет. Работаю с GULP, для копирования изображений пишу такой код
gulp.task('images', function(){
return gulp.src('./src/img/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/img/'))

})
изображения копируются, но работает только .svg формат, .png,.jpg перестают работать и не отображаются. Подскажите, пожалуйста в чем проблема?

Нашел ответ на stackoverflow по этой ссылке https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1574870/471649

Дело в том что начиная с 5ой версии gulp.src кодирует все файлы в текстовом формате, из за этого изображения "бьются".
Нужно отключить это следующим образом:
gulp.task('images', function(){
return gulp.src('./src/img/**/*', {encoding: false})
.pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/img/'))


при этом svg по умолчанию текстовый (вы можете даже зайти в файл и убедиться в этом - там простая html разметка), поэтому он не ломается
